# kineticjs - mask/contain images so no overlap

Tags: html, canvas, containers, kineticjs, mask

i have 2 images on my stage underneath an overlay image of 2 frames. The user can drag each image as if they were positioninng each image inside a photo frame. The problem i have is the yoda image in this example can overlap and appear inside the darth vader frame on the left (and vice-versa), as shown here:

[image: overlap example]

jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vTLkn/

Is there a way of placing the images inside some form of container or rectangle to stop this so they cannot appear inside another 'frame'?

The final page could end up having up to 5 or 6 frames and images with each image able to be scaled up or down as well as being dragged by the user anywhere they want (i had looked at the `dragBoundsFunc` but i don't actually want to restrict where they place it just stop the overlapping.

I also tried using a rectangle as an image mask and the image as the `fillPatternImage` attribute but i cannot then drag and scale the image inside then, just the rectangle itself.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use a Kinetic Group plus “yoda cropping” to be sure your images don’t overlap**

[image]

First create a Group that will contain both the picture frame and the Yoda:

If you need to drag or scale, you would drag or scale the Group (all contained elements would react accordingly)

```
    var group=new Kinetic.Group({
        x:20,
        y:20,
        width:256,
        height:256,
        draggable:true
    })
    layer.add(group);
```

Then add Yoda image which has been cropped to fit in the picture frame.

Since this Yoda image in in the background (lower z-index), any slight overlap with the picture frame will be hidden by the larger picture frame.

Here, the Yoda would be bigger than the picture frame, so it needs to be cropped a bit.

```
        var inner=new Kinetic.Image({
            image:Yoda,
            x:44,
            y:44,
            width:168,
            height:162,
            crop:{
                x: 23,
                y: 38,
                width: 168,
                height: 162
            }

        });
        group.add(inner);
```

Finally, add the picture frame which will be scaled to fit in the group using width/height:

```
        var outer=new Kinetic.Image({
            image:pictureFrame,
            x:0,
            y:0,
            width:256,
            height:256,
        });
        group.add(outer);
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qGHZn/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var group=new Kinetic.Group({
        x:20,
        y:20,
        width:256,
        height:256,
        draggable:true
    })
    layer.add(group);

    //////////////////////////
    // START
    //////////////////////////


var frame=new Image();
frame.onload=function(){

    var pic=new Image();
    pic.onload=function(){

        var inner=new Kinetic.Image({
            image:pic,
            x:44,
            y:44,
            width:168,
            height:162,
            crop:{
                x: 23,
                y: 38,
                width: 168,
                height: 162
            }

        });
        group.add(inner);

        var outer=new Kinetic.Image({
            image:frame,
            x:0,
            y:0,
            width:256,
            height:256,
        });
        group.add(outer);

        layer.draw();
    }
    pic.src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg";

}
frame.src="woodenframe.png";


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed response markE, much appreciated. The only problem is i need the yoda image to be dragged and scaled on it's own rather than with the frame - the frame would be stationary and set at that size the whole time - i need to be able to move and scale the yoda/darth images on their own...any ideas??

Comment: so just to clarify i need to be able to position each image within the stationary frame, rather than both the frame and image together - without any overlap

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused about what you need. Are you wanting to drag Yoda into any empty frame from outside a frame? Or are you wanting to restrict repositioning entirely within a frame--maybe to see more/less of Yoda's face or light-sabre?

Comment: I am wanting to drag yoda around the screen but not have it appear inside/underneath the frame for darth vader (and vice-versa) if that makes sense?

Comment: So the frame is just an image overlay, but for instance I only want yoda to be seen on the right hand side and darth vader on the left hand side of the canvas?