# KineticJs- Image setScale control

Tags: kineticjs

when you drag images you can control their moving with dragBoundFunc. Is there something similar when you scaling? I want to set an image area in "part of a stage" and when i setScale for this image and make it bigger, i don't want to see parts which is bigger then image area i've set before. is it possible?

Comment: yes, you can write an appropriate clip function to remove the area of image outside the defined area

Comment: Thank you for you response Ani. But i can't use clip function properly because i want to make image draggable and scaled. I found another topic which is so close my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724293/kineticjs-mask-contain-images-so-no-overlap and unfortunately it didn't get solve

Comment: clip does not affect scaling and dragging. I've used clip function on a draggable & scalable object before (though it was a Rect instead of image). And as a general note, add code of what you have tried so far to get a faster answer. A fiddle wud be nice!

Comment: Thanks for help Ani, Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m74p9/52/

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/m74p9/53/